# Remove feminine ending in german using regex python

Tags: python, regex

In german language feminine endings are `['/innen','/in','/Innen','/In','Innen','In','innen']`. I want to remove them from the strings, that are in list.

I have come up with the following:

```
rm_gender = ['/innen','/in','/Innen','/In','Innen','In','innen']
test_list = ['Softwareentwickler',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Softwareentwickler',
 'Softwareentwickler',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Softwareentwickler',
 'Softwareentwickler',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Hard-Softwareentwickler',
 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',
 'Hard-Softwareentwickler',
 'Hard-Softwareentwickler',
 'Hard-Softwareentwickler']

result = [vac if any([substring in vac for substring in ['-In',' In']]) else re.sub('|'.join(rm_gender),'',vac) if vac[:2] not in 'In' else 'In' + re.sub('|'.join(rm_gender),'',vac) for vac in test_list]
```

But it doesn't work, because there is a space in front of words like 'SoftwareentwicklerInnen'. How can i correctly do it with regex?

Important is: i want to keep format of the string as it is. Just need to remove feminine ending( or I want to return corrected list of strings)

Comment: Do you want to keep the `rm_gender` variable and build the regex in a dynamic way?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't mind other approaches. Final result must be correct, that's the only requirement:)

Comment: Ok, so why `/`? You have not provided any example where `/In` is. Should occur after a letter only?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew because in the text sometimes words like Softwareentwickler/Innen pops up. I have to take care of them too

Comment: So, I was correct when choosing to match `/` only after a word char. `re.compile( r'(?:\b/|\B)i(?:nne)?n\b', re.I )` will work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
rm_gender_regex = re.compile( r'(?:\b/|\B)i(?:nne)?n\b', re.I )
result = [rm_gender_regex.sub('', vac) for vac in test_list]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jygRk6/3). *Details*:

- `(?:\b/|\B)` - either a `/` that is preceded with a word char or a position that is preceded with a word char
- `i` - `i`
- `(?:nne)?` - an optional `nne` substring
- `n` - a `n` char
- `\b` - a word boundary.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/tymNLw):

```py
import re
test_list = ['Softwareentwickler', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Softwareentwickler', 'Softwareentwickler', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Softwareentwickler', 'Softwareentwickler', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker',  'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Hard-Softwareentwickler', 'Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; SoftwareentwicklerInnen; InformatikerInnen; Statistiker', 'Hard-Softwareentwickler', 'Hard-Softwareentwickler', 'Hard-Softwareentwickler']
rm_gender_regex = re.compile( r'(?:\b/|\B)i(?:nne)?n\b', re.I )
result = [rm_gender_regex.sub('', vac) for vac in test_list]
for x in result:
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
Softwareentwickler
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Softwareentwickler
Softwareentwickler
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Softwareentwickler
Softwareentwickler
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Hard-Softwareentwickler
Data Scientist; DWH-BI Consultant; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker
Hard-Softwareentwickler
Hard-Softwareentwickler
Hard-Softwareentwickler
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
import re

test_list = test_list[0].split(";")
test_list.append("Informatikerin") # adding one ending with in - I don't know if this is a correct word!

pattern = re.compile("in(?:nen)?$", re.IGNORECASE)

[re.sub(pattern, "", x) for x in test_list]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['Data Scientists', ' DWH-BI Consultants', ' Softwareentwickler', ' Informatiker', ' Statistiker', 'Informatiker']
```

**FOLLOW UP**

If you want to rebuild the string as it was, jusr rejoin by ";":

```
";".join([re.sub(pattern, "", x) for x in test_list])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'Data Scientists; DWH-BI Consultants; Softwareentwickler; Informatiker; Statistiker;Informatiker'
```

If the idea is to match all the words in each line:

```
pattern = re.compile("(in(?:nen)?)(?=;|\.|,|;| |:|$)", re.IGNORECASE)

re.sub(pattern, "", "You are a Softwareentwicklerinnen: that is as nice as Informatikerin")
re.sub(pattern, "", "You are a Softwareentwicklerinnen; that is as nice as Informatikerin")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
'You are a Softwareentwickler: that is as nice as Informatiker'
'You are a Softwareentwickler; that is as nice as Informatiker'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i want to keep the format of a string as it is.
I just want to remove feminin ending

Comment: @DanielYefimov so in your real example you have got a text, not a list of jobs?

Comment: I want to return corrected list of strings. Expanded my example

Answer (score 3):

You could convert matches of the following regular expression to empty strings:

```
\/?[Ii](?:nnen|n)\b
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BZt0nc/1)

This regex can be broken down as follows.

```
\/?         # optionally match '/'
[Ii]        # match 'I' or 'i'
(?:nnen|n)  # match 'nnen' or 'n' (in that order)
\b          # match a word boundary
```

The word boundary is to prevent matches of strings such as `innenantenne'